Access SQL Server in docker container from other container in Azure pipeline
We're at the beginning of a project, where we will create a rather large model and use entity framework core (EF) code first to create the database.
To have a graphical representation of the model and see how properties are configured and entities relate to each other, we would like to use Schemaspy to generate the documentation with below steps:

Start an MS SQL Server in a docker container (Docker Image)
Create the DB in the container (using EF migrations)
Use Schemaspy (Docker Image) to generate the documentation from the DB

These steps work fine locally, on a Windows workstation, with docker desktop
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=schema@spy!Secret2' -p 1437:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

cd .\medicaldata-api\src\MedicalData.DataAccess

dotnet ef database update --context MedicalDataDbContext --connection "Server=localhost,1437;Database=MedicalData;User Id=sa;Password=schema@spy!Secret2;TrustServerCertificate=true"

cd ..\..\..

docker run -v $PWD/output:/output -v $PWD/drivers:/drivers schemaspy/schemaspy -t mssql05 -db MedicalData -host host.docker.internal -port 1437 -u sa -p schema@spy!Secret2 -connprops "trustServerCertificate\=true" -I ".*History$" -X ".*\.(CreatedOn|CreatedBy|UpdatedOn|UpdatedBy|PeriodStart|PeriodEnd)"

When translating the PowerShell commands to an Azure pipeline, using docker compose, I can't connect to the DB (neither for EF migrations, nor with Schemaspy) and don't understand why.
schemaspy-docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.4'

services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "schema@spy!Secret2"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"

  schemaspy:
    image: schemaspy/schemaspy
    volumes:
      - ../output:/output
      - ../drivers:/drivers
    command: [
      "-t", "mssql05",
      "-db", "MedicalData",
      "-host", "mssql",
      "-port", "1433",
      "-u", "sa",
      "-p", "schema@spy!Secret2",
      "-connprops", "trustServerCertificate\\=true",
      "-I", ".*History$$",
      "-X", ".*\\.(CreatedOn|CreatedBy|UpdatedOn|UpdatedBy|PeriodStart|PeriodEnd)",
      "-debug"
    ]
    depends_on:
      - mssql


schemaspy.yml:
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  jdbcDriverUrl: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2272555'
  driversDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/drivers'

steps:
- script: |
    mkdir -p $(driversDirectory)
    wget --content-disposition $(jdbcDriverUrl) -P $(driversDirectory)
    unzip $(driversDirectory)/*.zip -d $(driversDirectory)
  displayName: 'Download and extract JDBC driver'

- script: |
    docker-compose -f azure-pipelines/schemaspy-docker-compose.yml up -d mssql
    dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
    cd src/MedicalData.DataAccess
    echo "Waiting for 1 minute before running database update..."
    sleep 1m
    echo "Starting database update"
    if ! dotnet ef database update --context MedicalDataDbContext --connection "Server=mssql,1433;Database=MedicalData;User Id=sa;Password=schema@spy!Secret2;TrustServerCertificate=true"; then
        echo "dotnet ef database update failed"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Finished database update"
    cd ../../
    docker-compose -f azure-pipelines/schemaspy-docker-compose.yml up schemaspy
    schemaspyExitCode=$?
    if [ $schemaspyExitCode -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Schemaspy failed with exit code $schemaspyExitCode"
        exit 1
    fi
  displayName: 'Run SchemaSpy with Docker Compose'


The yml files live in the directory azure-pipelines
The if statements in the schemaspy pipeline are there to fail early, if a step fails.

When running the pipeline, we can see the first two steps - launching the mssql container and installing ef tools - are successfully executed. Then the project is built (Build started.., Build succeeded) and the migration fails, because the connection to the DB can't be established.
Pulling mssql (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest)...
2022-latest: Pulling from mssql/server
Digest: sha256:c4369c38385eba011c10906dc8892425831275bb035d5ce69656da8e29de50d8
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
Creating azure-pipelines_mssql_1 ... 
Creating azure-pipelines_mssql_1 ... done
You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-ef
Tool 'dotnet-ef' (version '8.0.6') was successfully installed.
Waiting for 1 minute before running database update...
Starting database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

I suspect an issue either in the way the mssql is set up or in the connection string ("Server=mssql,1433;Database=MedicalData;User Id=sa;Password=schema@spy!Secret2;TrustServerCertificate=true"). Any idea?

Aside... the SA_PASSWORD environment variable has been deprecated for a couple of years now. It is recommended to transition to MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD as per the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server image documentation.

Published ports (i.e.: -p 1437:1433 and ports: - "1437:1433") are relevant to the Docker host, but inter-container communications should still be occurring using the containers' exposed ports. That is to say, have you tried connecting to mssql,1433 from your schemaspy container? Also be aware that SQL Server containers can take 30 seconds or more to get to the point of accepting incoming connections, depending on how many system and user databases they have to upgrade and rollback transactions for.

Thanks for the hints @AlwaysLearning! I've changed the config to use MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD, configure port mapping as 1433:1433, adapted the connection string and Schemaspy port to 1433 and also added a 1 minute sleep before launching the migration. Unfortunately the behavior and exception message remain the same. (I've updated the post to include these changes)

Have you monitored the log console of the mssql container for any error messages during its own startup, or while the other connections are being attempted?

One assumes that you haven't posted your actual passwords here (and, really, you should be creating application-specific SQL Logins and passwords instead of using the sa account), but it's possible that the specified passwords don't meet SQL Server's minimum complexity requirements and/or they contain certain characters such as ! that have special significance to shells like bash.

No worries about the password, it's only used for the sql server running in the container, which only lives while running the pipeline. It will have the schema set up but no data. Logs don't show anything out of the ordinary, I'll try to increase verbosity to have better insight. And will also follow your other leads. (I'm doing my first steps with docker containers in Azure DevOps and got a lot to learn)

@Philippe Can you try to add the Encrypt=False to your connectionstring? For example:  "Server=mssql,1433;Database=MedicalData;User Id=sa;Password=schema@spy!Secret2;TrustServerCertificate=true;Encrypt=False" Then you can check if it can work.

Hi @KevinLu-MSFT tried it with Encrypt=False but the network issue remained.

@Philippe If possible, can you get the ip adress and add it to the server field. For example: "Server=IPadress,1433;Database=MedicalData;User Id=sa;Password=schema@spy!Secret2;TrustServerCertificate=true;Encrypt=False"
